# Oracle Apex add text to same page field after submit page button clicked?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I'm having a stressful issue with Oracle Apex. After pressing submit on a button (which is set to submit page) I would like validations to occur and then after that a message to appear as text into a display only text field. So when the page submits and "refreshes" the fields are cleared and the display only field := 'successful addition' or whatever. However, the page submits successfully but the after submit process to add the text into the display only field doesn't work. Do you guys know a way around this?

Comment: You're really going to need to provide much more information about what you've done so far, perhaps even with example on apex.oracle.com. It's likely you're clearing the session state value when branching after submit processing.

Answer (score 1):

One aproach is to set the source of your DISPLAY_ONLY item to be your TEXT_FIELD item.
For more sophisticated solutions you can use Branch or Process.

[For example: my TEXT_FIELD is named: P10_SOURCE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TY5wj.jpg)

Comment: Thank you. I've solved it by altering the sequence of validations and processes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, all.

I've solved it by altering the sequence of validations and processes.